# How do I make the css load in CodeIgniter in an xampp development environment?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, development-environment

I am setting up a local CodeIgniter development environment on my windows machine using xampp. I am having a little bit of trouble with the css files. I am guessing that I need to configure my application's path somewhere.

The development url is this (this is routed to the home page ):

```
localhost/my_app
```

I am linking my stylesheet like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

on a production server this works just fine, but the css will not load locally because it seems to be linking to `localhost/css/style.css` instead of `localhost/my_app/css/style.css`.

when I change the link to this, it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my_app/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

this link works, but still will not load the `background-image:url('/images/image.png')` I am using.

I don't want to code all of my paths with `my_app/directory_i_want_to_access` because then I will have to go back and change them whenever I push to production.

Comment: Can't you use relative paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

For image links within CSS, say this is your folder structure

```
/ Assets
| - /images
| - | - image.png
| - /css
| - | - / style.css
```

Just link to the images relative to the CSS file, so in this case, it'll be `../images/image.png`

Comment: That works great thanks. I still have a problem with the background-image:url(/images/image.png) though. I don't think I can write php into a css file.

Comment: No, for images within the CSS file, they only check the path relative to the css file. So, just put it in the same place, and use `(../images/image.png)` if your CSS file is in the CSS folder and images in images folder inside the same assets folder

Answer (score 0):

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
```

add that you your html file, your links should work now.

courtesy of phil sturgeon